# Terraform installing multiple versions of azurerm provider

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We've been using older versions of both Terraform and the azurerm provider and I'm trying to update the code for newer (for us) versions of each, in this case:

- Terraform: v0.13.7
- azurerm: v2.25

As part of the recoding, I'm switching to using the Terraform provider block:

```
terraform {
  required_version  = "~> 0.13"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = "= 2.25.0"
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }
}
provider azurerm {
  skip_provider_registration = true
  features {}
}
```

Terraform is downloading v2.25 of the provider but also the most version v2.67:

```
$ terraform init 

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "2.25.0"...
- Finding latest version of -/azurerm...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.25.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v2.25.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing -/azurerm v2.67.0...
- Installed -/azurerm v2.67.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
```

So far this doesn't seem to be an issue, but I cannot understand why it's downloading multiple versions.  Could it be because, in another code file which defines the backend (we use Azure storage for Terraform state), it's seeing that "azurerm" reference and treating it as a "new" one?

```
terraform {
  backend azurerm {
    container_name       = "terraforminfra-v2"
    key                  = "state/postgres.tfstate"
  }
}
```

Comment: The provider is probably being specified with both the old and new namespaces in different `required_providers` blocks. Upgrading to Terraform 0.14 would prompt you to resolve this issue, since that version requires the new namespace.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out ... the "old" reference to the provider was still in the Terraform state, which I think is what was triggering the download of the most current version.